# How to add <pre> tag inside the <p> in html?

Tags: html

I'm using below code it is throwing the `<pre>` outside the `<p>`. So, is there any way to insert `<pre>` inside `<p>`. below I'm attaching my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <p>
      <pre>
        dkjaskldjasklda
        skladjasklda
      </pre>
   </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, Who or what is *"throwing the `<pre>` outside the `<p>`"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<pre>` is a block-level element and `<p>` is not. It's not possible to put block-level elements inside `<p>`.

If you use the `<p>` for creating whitespace, you can solve this by adding a margin-bottom to the `<pre>` tag.

Comment: Nitpicking: it *is* perfectly possible to nest them (`<p><pre>See, I did it!</pre></p>`), it just isn't valid HTML5 according to the specification. ;)

Comment: @SatyaNaiduPendem: what exactly is not working? Do you know how to use CSS to add margin to the `<pre>` tag?

Comment: `<pre style="margin-bottom: 1em"></pre>` or you could read up on how to make stylesheets.

Comment: Satya, the point is that you should **not** put the `pre` inside the `p` to begin with!